# Accessing an enum within namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

I am having some problems accessing enums that are wrapped in namespaces.

My issue is that I have two namespaces for two different implementations of an algorithm. The issue is I have two enums for the modes in each namespace, each being slightly different. In one file I want to compare the two implementations. The issue arises that I cannot then use the enums without the two clashing. Can any one describe how I might go about doing this without `using namespace`

```
namespace implementation1{
enum modes {mode_standard, mode_special, fast_mode}
}
namespace implementation2{
enum modes {mode_default, mode_repeat, fast_mode}
}
```

Note this is just an example mine is a bit more complex but it demonstrates what i want to do. I want to try and solve it this way as opposed to refactoring into a global enum or renaming the modes, though that is an option if there is no other way.

Comment: Have you tried namespace1::mode1? Did it work? If not, what was the actual result? In general you access an enum exactly as you would access any other name.

Comment: Thanks I think that got it going. I had misunderstood that concept when i tried working this out. Thanks for the help (I'm still pretty new with namespaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what is your problem, but this work ok for you? if not, please elaborate more on the example:

```
namespace implementation1 {
enum modes { mode_standard, mode_special, fast_mode };
}
namespace implementation2 {
enum modes { mode_default, mode_repeat, fast_mode };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (implementation1::fast_mode == implementation2::fast_mode) { // foo mode use...
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Updating an `enum` can break your "equivalence":

```
namespace implementation1 {
enum modes { mode_standard, mode_special, fast_mode };
}
namespace implementation2 {
enum modes { first_mode, mode_default, mode_repeat, fast_mode };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // foo mode use... this not work now
  if (implementation1::fast_mode == implementation2::fast_mode) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The `enum` values are automatically assigned, if you need compare the `enum`s from his name you need menage the "assigned value" manually:

```
namespace implementation1 {
enum modes { mode_standard, mode_special, fast_mode = 3 };
}
namespace implementation2 {
enum modes { first_mode, mode_default, mode_repeat, fast_mode = 3 };
}
```

but it is error prone, I strongly recommend do not use this, if you
need details about this I recommend [read](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) about the motivations about the new [scoped](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Enumeration_scope) enums(eg: `enum class`), available from c++11.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment. I was trying to determine how to access the enum its self. however I do have a question, if I gave two enums the same values within two different namespaces would they be equivalent (e.g. both are exactly identical except for namespace)